# Optimization or merging of EF Core 3 Queries

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, entity-framework-core

I have a sql database containing a table of conntections between different points. Now i want to find all points which are somehow connected to a given point. I want to get the complete connection tree. 
I implemented a class Node which contains a point and its in- and outputs (other points).
The method GetContainingTree(List connectionsTable, int startingPoint) uses the connectionTable to find all connected points and return them as a Node.

```
public class Connection
    {
        public int SourcePoint { get; set; }
        public int DestinationPoint { get; set; }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public int Point { get; set; }
        public List<int> Inputs { get; set; }
        public List<int> Outputs { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string desc = "Name: " + Point + "\n";
            desc += "\nInputs:\n";
            foreach(int i in Inputs)
            {
                desc += i.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            desc += "\nOutputs:\n";
            foreach (int o in Outputs)
            {
                desc += o.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            return desc;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Connection> connectionTable = new List<Connection>();

            // connection tree on
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 1, DestinationPoint = 2 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 1, DestinationPoint = 3 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 3, DestinationPoint = 4 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 2, DestinationPoint = 4 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 4, DestinationPoint = 5 });

            // connection tree two
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 6, DestinationPoint = 7 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 7, DestinationPoint = 8 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 7, DestinationPoint = 9 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 7, DestinationPoint = 10 });
            connectionTable.Add(new Connection() { SourcePoint = 9, DestinationPoint = 11 });


            List<Node> tree1 = GetContainingTree(connectionTable, 4);
            List<Node> tree2 = GetContainingTree(connectionTable, 11);

            Console.WriteLine("Tree One:");
            foreach(Node n in tree1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Tree Two:");
            foreach (Node n in tree2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }


        }

        private static List<Node> GetContainingTree(List<Connection> connectionsTable, int startingPoint)
        {
            List<int> pointsToSearch = new List<int>() { startingPoint };
            List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();

            while(pointsToSearch!=null && pointsToSearch.Count>0)
            {
                foreach(int pointToSearch in pointsToSearch)
                {
                    Node node = new Node() { Point = pointToSearch };
                    // search for outputs
                    var outputs = from connection in connectionsTable
                                  where connection.SourcePoint == pointToSearch
                                  select connection.DestinationPoint;

                    // search for inputs
                    var inputs = from connection in connectionsTable
                                 where connection.DestinationPoint == pointToSearch
                                 select connection.SourcePoint;

                    node.Inputs = inputs.ToList();   // execute the query on db server
                    node.Outputs = outputs.ToList();  // execute the query on db server

                    nodes.Add(node);
                }


                // update the pointsToSearch
                var allPointsInNodes = nodes.SelectMany(n => n.Inputs);
                allPointsInNodes.Union(nodes.SelectMany(n => n.Outputs));

                // remove all found node names
                pointsToSearch = allPointsInNodes.Where(p => !nodes.Select(n => n.Point).ToList().Contains(p))
                                                 .Distinct()
                                                 .ToList();
            }

            return nodes;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Tree One:
Name: 4

Inputs:
3
2

Outputs:
5

Name: 3

Inputs:
1

Outputs:
4

Name: 2

Inputs:
1

Outputs:
4

Name: 1

Inputs:

Outputs:
2
3

Tree Two:
Name: 11

Inputs:
9

Outputs:

Name: 9

Inputs:
7

Outputs:
11

Name: 7

Inputs:
6

Outputs:
8
9
10

Name: 6

Inputs:

Outputs:
7
```

My solution works but it uses many individually executed database queries. I would like to merge as many of these queries as possible, to get this more performant. Is there a way to have summarize the logic of GetContainingTree(...) into one query? I dont care if have to use query or method syntax.

I think it would be possible to merge this query in to a server sided function on the sql server, but i want to keep the freedom to change my database engine later on.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With only entity framework and linq you can not reduce the number of queries issued to server. You could use common table expression(CTE) to fetch the data in one query. You could pass query with CTE to `dbContext.FromSqlRaw` and get the result.